# Prove that generalized mean of two values lies between them

Tags: analysis

Let $a > 0; b > 0$ and $S =(\frac{a^p + b^p}{2})^\frac{1}{p}$.

It is needed to prove that $a \leq S \leq b$. (1)

Now, I have a proof, but not sure about it mathematical correctness.

Let $a \leq b$. Then b can be represented as $ka; k \geq 1$.

$S =(\frac{a^p + (ka)^p}{2})^\frac{1}{p}$.

If $k=1$ then $S=a$ which is self-explaining.

Now assume $k > 1$

$S =a(\frac{k^p + 1}{2})^\frac{1}{p}$.

So to prove (1) in this case we need to compare $(\frac{k^p + 1}{2})^\frac{1}{p}$ with 1 and $k$.

So as $\lim (\frac{k^p + 1}{2})^\frac{1}{p}_{p \to \infty}=1$

then

$\lim (S-1)_{p \to \infty}=0$, which means that $S-a \geq 0$

and as $k>1$

$\lim (S-k)_{p \to \infty} < 0 $,  which means that $S-b \leq 0 $

1) Is this correct

2) If not is it possible to prove it this way and how

3) If way of proof is wrong right proof is welcome

Answer (score 1):

we have

$$0<a<b$$

thus

$$a^p<\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}<b^p$$

we apply now  the power

$\frac{1}{p}$

to get the desired result.